# Make WinEdt spell-check in another language

Tags: winedt, spelling

What is the simplest way to make WinEdt (10.2 if it makes a difference) to spell-check in another language?

In my case the other language is Swedish.

Answer (score 7):

First download the Swedish dictionary from WinEdt.org and install it (on the same site, you can download the `InstallDict` macro to make it easier).

Next, in the Options Interface, click on the Dictionary Manager section, and more specifically on the last but one icon (on the left of the question mark) to launch the Dictionary Manager. Select the Swedish dictionary, and choose from this interface how it will be used (load on start, add new words, &c.).

It might be interesting to define a, say, `SV` submode for documents written in Swedish, the dictionary being loaded and used only for files having this submode.

As an illustration, a screenshot of my own configuration (for the French language, not Swedish!):

[image]

*Unrelated* : you should update to the last version of WinEdt (10.3).